# Emailing Error Report from Coldfusion Administrator

Tags: logging, coldfusion

We run an app that doesn't have great email notifications for errors but they do end up in the application.log in Coldfusion. Does Coldfusion have a way to send an email when this file changes and it's an error (not just a session rotation or other info level log entry)?

Comment: Maybe you want to try and check Hoth https://github.com/aarongreenlee/Hoth

Comment: Don't monitor that file for errors, use proper error handling in all of your ColdFusion applications - [handling errors in ColdFusion](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/handling-errors.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution but it might get you headed in the right direction. I haven't worked on CF watching the error log files and emailing - you'd want to set up a scheduled task to check it. But I will say that server error of type 500 were a thorn in my side because IIS didn't want to want to pass the error to CF to handle. Here's the page I am using to open the error log, get to the bottom and work backwards to display the 500-type errors. It's not terribly robust, but it does let me review the errors I used to not get notified about:

```
<cffile action="read" variable="exceptionLog" file="C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\logs\exception.log">
<cfparam name="form.goBack" default="0">
<cfparam name="form.showHowMany" default="10">
<cfif structKeyExists(url,"goback") and  structKeyExists(url,"showHowMany")>
    <cfset form.goBack=url.goback>
    <cfset form.showHowMany=url.showHowMany>
</cfif>
<cfoutput>
<cfset bodyAttr=' style="font-family:arial;font-size:10pt;font-weight:normal;"'>
<cfinclude template="../html_header.cfm">
<form name="f" id="f" action="cfexception.cfm" method="post">
Go back<input name="goBack" id="goBack" class="intgr" size="4" value="#form.goBack#"> &nbsp;
Show how many<input name="showHowMany" id="showHowMany" class="intgr" size="4" value="#form.showHowMany#"> &nbsp;
<input type="button" value="Go" id="btnSbmt">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.intgr").keyup(function (e) { // Filter non-digits from input value.
        if (/\D/g.test($(this).val())) $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
    });
    $("##btnSbmt").click(function(){
        if($("##goBack").val()=="" || $("##goBack").val()=="") alert("Both input fields (Go back and Show how many) are required.");
        else $("##f").submit();
    })
});
</script>
</cfoutput>
<cfset raText=listToArray(exceptionLog,chr(10))>
<cfset raErr=[]>
<cfset goneBack=0>
<cfset showHowMany=1>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="#arrayLen(raText)#" to="1" step="-1" index="idxErr">
    <cfif findNoCase("error",raText[idxErr])>
        <cfif goneBack lte form.goBack><cfset goneBack=goneBack+1><!--- display nothing, incr counter --->
        <cfelse><!--- now that we've gone far enough back, start displaying --->
            <strong>#showHowMany#</strong>#raText[idxErr]# <cfif idxErr neq (arrayLen(raText)-1)><br />#raText[idxErr+1]#</cfif><br /><br />
            <cfif int(showHowMany) lte int(form.showHowMany)-1><cfset showHowMany=showHowMany+1>
            <cfelse><cfbreak><!--- incr counter up to number user entered (or default) and then bail out --->
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
</body>
</html>
</cfoutput>
```